# How should I make images change based on a variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im using Tkinter to create a button which has an image on it, and I want it to change every time the variable is updated or when the function that requires it to update is called.

This is what I have:

```
from Tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

i1 = PhotoImage(file='resources/1.png')
b1 = Button(tk, image=i1, command=c1)

# this all the way to i151 and b151
```

I want it to change every time the variable changes, and I don't want to make a function with 151 globals to do it

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? As an aside, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: What do you recommend using instead?

Comment: Just `import Tkinter`, no?

Comment: What are the variables?

Comment: oh lol im so stupid. I found the answer to my question, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your present code has the function callback c1 when button b1 pressed:

```
i1 = PhotoImage(file='resources/1.png')
b1 = Button(tk, image=i1, command=c1)
```

In your function c1 (or another function) you can trigger the image to be updated.

```
def c1():
    i1.config(file="resources/2.png")
```

You'd need to be more specific about the changing variable triggering the image change. How is this variable being changed?

Comment: I have a dictionary with variables, and I want it so once one changes the image also changes when a function that loads it onto the screen is called